# Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: android, react-native

I get an error when I run the android device. Error when i use this function

```
    function undoNote(index){
        let getBack = props.moveToBin[index];
        let array = [getBack, ...props.notes];
        props.setNotes(array);

        let newArray = [...props.moveToBin];
        newArray.splice(index, 1);
        props.setMoveToBin(newArray);

        AsyncStorage.setItem('storedNotes', JSON.stringify(array)).then(() => {
            props.setNotes(array)
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))

        AsyncStorage.setItem('deletedNotes', () => {
            return;
        })
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The error is probably not in the code you provided, since it's getting a stylesheet as an argument. What in your project has an opacity of 6?

Comment: Oh, however, when I removed the code described below, the error did not happen.
 '''
AsyncStorage.setItem('deletedNotes', () => {
            return;
        })
'''

Comment: I missed that. That's not valid to save into AsyncStorage because it doesn't serialize into a string. That's at least one issue.